# Expo React Native TakeSnapShot Async Returning Black Screen

Tags: react-native, camera, expo

I'm new to React Native and am trying to create an app that will use Expo's Camera and Takesnapshot Async to take a picture and save it to Cameraroll.

I'm probably doing something really dumb, but right now (even though the view is showing the camera before I press the snapshot button), my code is saving a black image when I click the button instead of the image captured by the camera to the camera roll.

Here is my code for the CameraScreen (I'm using code from https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera to open the camera and code from https://snack.expo.io/SJRvlSxvb to save a snapshot):

```
class CameraScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
    cameraRollUri: null,
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
  }

  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <View />;
    } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
          <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} 
            type={this.state.type}
            collapsable={false}
              ref={view => {
                this._container = view;
              }} >
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }} >

            {this.state.cameraRollUri &&
            <Image
              source={{ uri: this.state.cameraRollUri }}
              style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }
            }
            />}

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.gridItem} onPress={this._saveToCameraRollAsync}>
            </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  flex: 0.1,
                  alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                    type: this.state.type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                      ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                      : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
                  });
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}>
                  {' '}Flip{' '}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
          </Camera>
        </View>
      );
    }


  }
    _saveToCameraRollAsync = async () => {
    let result = await takeSnapshotAsync(this._container, {
      format: 'png',
      result: 'file',
    });

    let saveResult = await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(result, 'photo');
    this.setState({ cameraRollUri: saveResult });
  };
}
```

I first thought that the view saved to this._components wasn't the right view, but I tried attaching the code

```
ref={view => {
                this._container = view;
              }
```

to different views in the class but nothing seems to be changing.

Thanks in advance for any help - I've been struggling for this for a pretty long time now :(

PS: This is my first stack overflow post; I apologize in advance if there anything wrong with my post.

Answer (score 1):

Expo Camera doesn’t support snapshot instead you can use the method `takePictureAsync` from Camera which return an image object.

```
const image = await this._container.takePictureAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Camera component from Expo doesn't support `takeSnapshotAsync`.

Otherwise if you are using any Expo-pixi component, this code can be helpful:

```
const { uri } = await this.sketch.takeSnapshotAsync();

//save sketch/signature/doodles in DCIM folder.

let saveResult = await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri, 'photo');
```